# How to find if there are wrong values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new in Python coding, and I am dealing with a big dataframe for my internship.

I had an issue as sometimes there are wrong values in my dataframe. For example I find string type values (`"broken leaf"`) instead of integer type values as (`"120 cm"`) or (`NaN`).

I know there is the `df.replace()` function, but therefore you need to know that there are wrong values. So how do I find if there are any wrong values inside my dataframe?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hard to know, because a "wrong" value depends on the problem you're working on, but if there aren't supposed to be *too* many different values in a given column, you can take a look using `df['column name'].unique()`. Sometimes the "wrong" values pop out at you when you do that (for instance, a string would be obvious in a column that is supposed to be all integers)

Comment: Use regex to find which rows match the format of your expected 'correct' values. So if they should all be numbers followed by a space and then units you can match that.

Answer (score 0):

"120 cm" is a string, not an integer, so that's a confusing example.  Some ways to find "unexpected" values include:

**Use "describe"** to examine the range of numerical values, to see if there are any far outside of your expected range.

**Use "unique"** to see the set of all values for cases where you expect a small number of permitted values, like a gender field.

**Look at the datatypes of columns** to see whether there are strings creeping in to fields that are supposed to be numerical.

**Use regexps** if valid values for a particular column follow a predictable pattern.